# Recursive python matching algorithm based on subsets working too slowly

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, match, subset

I'm building a web app to match high school students considering a gap year to students who have taken a gap year, based on interest as denoted by tags. A prototype is up at [covidgapyears.com](http://www.covidgapyears.com/). I have never written a matching/recommendation algorithm, so though people have suggested things like collaborative filtering and association rule mining, or adapting the stable marriage problem, I don't think any of those will work because it's a small dataset (few hundred users right now, few thousand soon). So I wrote my own alg using common sense.

It essentially takes in a list of tags that the student is interested it, then searches for an exact match *of those tags* with someone who has taken a gap year and registered with the site (who also selected tags on registration). An exactMatch, as given below, is when the tags the user specifies are ALL contained by some profile (i.e., are a subset). If it can't find an exact match with ALL of the user's inputted tags, *it will check all n-1 length subsets of the tags list itself to see if any less selective queries have matches*. It does this recursively until at least 3 matches are found. While it works fine for small tags selections (up to 5-7) it gets slow for larger tags selections (7-13), taking several seconds to return a result. When 11-13 tags are selected, hits a Heroku error due to worker timeout.

I did some tests by putting variables inside the algorithm to count computations and it seems that when it goes a bit deep into the recursive stack, it checks a few hundred subsets each time (to see if there's an exactMatch for that subset, and if there is, add it to results list to output), and the total number of computations doubles as you add one more tag (it went 54, 150, 270, 500, 1000, 1900, 3400 operations for more and more tags). It is true that there are a few hundred subsets at each depth. But exactMatches is O(1) as I've written it (no iteration), and aside from the other O(1) operations like IF, the FOR inside the subset loop will, at most, be gone through around 10 times. This agrees with the measured result of a few thousand computations each time.

This did not surprise me as selecting and iterating over all subsets seems to be something that could get non harder, but my question is about why it's so slow despite only doing a few thousand computations. I know my computer operates in GHz and I expect web servers are similar, so surely a few thousand computations would be near-instantaneous? What am I missing and how can I improve this algorithm? Any other approaches I should look into?

```
# takes in a list of length n and returns a list of all combos of subsets of depth n
def arbSubsets(seq, n):
    return list(itertools.combinations(seq, len(seq)-n))

# takes in a tagsList and check Gapper.objects.all to see if any gapper has all those tags
def exactMatches(tagsList):
    tagsSet = set(tagsList)
    exactMatches = []
    for gapper in Gapper.objects.all():
        gapperSet = set(gapper.tags.names())
        if tagsSet.issubset(gapperSet):
            exactMatches.append(gapper)
    return exactMatches

# takes in tagsList that has been cleaned to remove any tags that NO gappers have and then checks gapper objects to find optimal match
def matchGapper(tagsList, depth, results):
    # handles the case where we're only given tags contained by no gappers
    if depth == len(tagsList):
        return []
    # counter variable is to measure complexity for debugging
    counter += 1
    # we don't want too many results or it stops feeling tailored
    upper_limit_results = 3
    # now we must check subsets for match
    subsets = arbSubsets(tagsList, depth)
    for subset in subsets:
        counter += 1
        matches = exactMatches(subset)
        if matches:
            for match in matches:
                counter += 1
                # new need to check because we might be adding depth 2 to results from depth 1
                #  which we didn't do before, to make sure we have at least 3 results
                if match not in results:
                    # don't want to show too many or it doesn't feel tailored anymore
                    counter += 1
                    if len(results) > upper_limit_results: break
                    results.append(match)
    # always give at least 3 results
    if len(results) > 2:
        return results
    else:
        # check one level deeper (less specific) into tags if not enough gappers that match to get more results
        counter += 1
        return matchGapper(tagsList, depth + 1, results)

# this is the list of matches we then return to the user 
matches = matchGapper(tagsList, 0, [])
```

Comment: The Time-complexity of intertools.combinations is O(n!), n being the length of the array. That is the main issue I guess

Comment: Don't think this is the problem. See my comment about itertools on Ivaylo's answer.

Comment: To make an accurate count, `counter` must be global. Define `counter` outside of `matchGapper` and include the line, `global counter` at the top of that function. Then print `counter` once the program terminates. One method you could consider is "tabu search" if the match does not to be strict.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so after much fiddling with timers I've figured it out. There are a few functions at play when matching: exactMatches, matchGapper and arbSubset. When I put the counter into a global variable and measured operations (as measured as lines of *my code* being executed, it came in **around 2-10K for large inputs** (around 10 tags)).

It is true that arbSubset, which returns a list of subsets, at first seems like a plausible bottleneck. But if you look closely, we are 1) handling small amounts of tags (order of 10-50) and more importantly, 2) we are only calling arbSubset when we recurse matchGapper, which only happens a max of about 10 times, since tagsList can only be around 10 (order of 10-50, as above). And when I checked the time it took to generate arbSubsets, it was order of 2e-5. And so the total time spend on *generating* the subsets of arbitrary size is only 2e-4. In other words, not the source of the 5-30 second waiting time in the web app.

And so with that aside, knowing that arbSubset is only called on the order of 10 times, and is fast at that, and knowing that there are only around a max of 10K computations taking place *in my code* it starts to become clear that I must be using some out-of-the-box function, I don't know--like set() or .issubset() or something like that--that takes a nontrivial amount of time to compute, and is executed many times. Adding some counters in some more places, it becomes clear that exactMatch() accounts for around 95-99% of all computations that take place (as would be expected if we have to check all combinations of subsets of various sizes for exactMatches).

So the problem, at this point, is reduced to the fact that exactMatch takes around 0.02s (empirically) as implemented, and is called several thousand times. And so we can either try to make it faster by a couple of order of magnitudes (it's already pretty optimal), or take another approach that doesn't involve finding matches using subsets. A friend of mine suggested creating a dict with all the combinations of tags (so 2^len(tagsList) keys) and setting them equal to lists of registered profiles with that exact combination. This way, querying is just traversing a (huge) dict, which can be done fast. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem you are doing a few hundred computation steps. In fact you have a few hundred options for each depth, thus you should not add, but multiply the number of steps at each depth to estimate the complexity of your solution.

Additionally this statement: `This or adapting the stable marriage problem, I don't think any of those will work because it's a small dataset` is also obviously not true. Although these algorithms may be overkill for some very simple cases, they are still valid and will work for them.

Comment: It is true that there are a few hundred subsets at each depth. But exactMatches is O(1) as I've written it (no iteration), and aside from the other O(1) operations like IF, the FOR inside the subset loop will, at most, be gone through around 10 times. The theoretical estimate of a few thousand computations that follow agrees, then, with the computation counter variable I put in after every step in matchGappers when debugging. I think I'm right on this part, at least. So it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Also, wrt existing algorithms, yes I don't know how to make this into a stable marriage problem so I wouldn't know how to adapt it but if I could it would work. However, the other suggestions were statistical (ML) approaches that would give bad results for small datasets and therefore would not work.

Comment: @TanishqKumar could you share how you implemented the counter variable? Empirical evidence shows that it can't be a few thousand steps

Comment: Added as counter variable. Perhaps the fact that I'm getting a few thousand as the counter for large tag input suggests the bottleneck is in itertools.combinations or in .issubset(), functions I haven't measured the internal computations of?

Comment: `itertools.combinations` is definitely not a simple but an exponential operation. `.issubset` is also (expected) linear instead of constant.

Comment: It can't be itertools: I just tested how long it's taking to find arbSubsets using time.start and time.end around the arbSubsets() call in matchGapper, and the time taken for arbSubsets with depth as 6 (it was roughly the same for 1-5) is:  2.193450927734375e-05. In other words, that's not the problem, so what might be?

Comment: How big is your tags list?

Comment: Size ranges from 1-13 tags that the user selects, but am thinking of offering more (up to 20 or 30) tags in the future to match by.